# case insensitive tag matching with xml-conduit?

Tags: html, haskell, xml-conduit

What's the best way to perform case-insensitive tag and attribute name matching using `xml-conduit`?

For example, consider the `findNodes` function from the HTML parsing example on FP Complete's School of Haskell:

https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/tagsoup

```
-- The data we're going to search for
findNodes :: Cursor -> [Cursor]
findNodes = element "span" >=> attributeIs "class" "sb_count" >=> child
```

(I've modified this line to that it will work with the Bing's current page structure.)

My experiments indicate that `element` and `attributeIs` do not perform case-insensitive comparisons when matching names. Is there an easy way to change this?

Comment: You appear to be parsing HTML, so consider using an HTML parser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [laxElement](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.2.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor.html#v:laxElement) to ignore case when matching elements. It will also ignore namespaces. It should be pretty easy to write a wrapper around `checkName` that has the exact semantics you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like laxElement will do what I want for tags.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a work-around... still interested in a cleaner solution.

Basically we just create our own version of `Text.HTML.DOM` which fixes up the tag and attribute names in tag event stream just before the XML tree is created.

The function `eventConduit` begins like this:

```
eventConduit :: Monad m => Conduit S.ByteString m XT.Event
eventConduit =
    TS.tokenStream =$= go []
  where
    go stack = do
        mx <- await
        case fmap (entities . fmap' (decodeUtf8With lenientDecode)) mx of
            Nothing -> closeStack stack
...
```

We change the `case fmap ...` line to:

```
        case fmap (entities . fixNames . fmap' (decodeUtf8With lenientDecode)) mx of
```

where `fixNames` is defined as:

```
fixNames :: TS.Token' Text -> TS.Token' Text
fixNames (TS.TagOpen x pairs b) = TS.TagOpen (T.toLower x) (map (T.toLower *** id) pairs) b
fixNames (TS.TagClose x)        = TS.TagClose (T.toLower x)
fixNames t                      = t
```

Now we just use lowercase names in `element` and `attributeIs`.